# Missing a step in a simplification of a probability union

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUpPq.jpg)

I am working through the First Course on Probability by Sheldon Ross. There was a question on the independent number of trials of coin flips. The trials are continual flips until tails are obtained or until n trials are made. I was able to write the probabilities and got the right answer. However, Ross then does a check on his answer using the union operator and I am stumped at one of the simplification steps (in the image). I feel it is something simple (pun intended) but I am missing it. I show what I did in the image.

Comment: Please, can you write directly the text of your question without posting a link to a photo of your handwriting?

Comment: Multiply both the numerator and denomintaor by $(1-p)$